# C# - Sum List<string[]>

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, list, sum

Suppose you have a list<string[]>

```
  List<string[]> lst = new List<string[]>();

  lst.Add(new string[] { "A", "100.10" });
  lst.Add(new string[] { "B", "250.49" });
```

How do you get a sum of the second array items in the list?

Will need to convert the second array items to double and sum them up. Expected result is **350.59**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use:

```
double sum = lst.Sum(i => double.Parse(i[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it list this:

```
lst
.Select(item => Decimal.Parse(item[1]))
.Sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double total = 0;

foreach(string[] stringArray in lst)
{
    total += Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[1]);
}
```

Comment: Surely you mean `ToDecimal()`?

Comment: @DaveShaw I'd actually think he'd way `ToDouble()`, considering he's adding into a `double`...